# Magento 2: how to create api to send the Hashkey value to Mobile Apps?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api, integration, android

I want to create PAYU API for Checksum generation at the Magento backend and send the Hash key value to Mobile Apps.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create an API from scratch for PAY U , you need use to their existing PHP SDK which helps to connect to their REST API.

> https://developer.payumoney.com/payumoney-php-integration-guide/
>
> http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html

1. In Magento create a module with rest api service classes (under Vendor/Module/Api directory) which should be properly configured in Vendor/Module/etc/webapi.xml and Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml.
2. Create the Model classes which use the PayU PHP SDK to connect with their API and do what you want to do.

[Refer this article](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-api/) for information on how to create a REST API in Magento 2

Hope this helps !

**Update**

PayU has Magento2 module which you can checkout

https://developer.payumoney.com/plugins/#Magento